# HTTR package is not returning full response from API query

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I am trying to use httr to call on an API from IGDB ([documentation here](https://api-docs.igdb.com/#about)). When I use the following query in Postman, I have no problem and get the full request which has 100 entries:

```
fields rating, game; where game = 114283; limit 100; sort id desc;
```

Example of entry here:

```
    {
        "id": 442667,
        "game": 114283,
        "rating": 3.0
    },
```

However, when I attempt to make this query in R using httr as follows:

```
  string <- paste0("rating, game; where game = ", ids[1,1], "; limit 100; sort id desc;")
  data <- POST("https://api-v3.igdb.com/private/rates/",
              add_headers("user-key" = "XXXXXXXXXX"),
              query = list(fields = string)
                           )
  fromJSON(rawToChar(data$content))
```

it returns only a data frame of 23 rows:

```
       id   game rating
1  442667 114283      3
...
23 383956 114283     10
```

Other calls similarly return shortened data frames with varying length depending upon the query.

If anyone has any idea as to why this might be happening, I would love some insight.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're merely passing your query string in wrongly, since it is supposed to be passed into the `-d` (data) parameter of your http request.

Try the following:

1. append the initial "fields " into `string`
2. pass this to the `body` param of your `POST` request

So:

```
string <- paste0("fields rating, game; where game = ", ids[1,1], "; limit 100; sort id desc;")
data <- POST(
  "https://api-v3.igdb.com/private/rates/",
  add_headers("user-key" = "XXXXXXXXXX"),
  body = string
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, I tried this and it changes nothing with the response.

Comment: Having looked at the `/games/` endpoint, this game should be  https://m.igdb.com/games/persona-5-royal, right? It only has 26 rates + reviews, which checks out with the results coming from those two endpoints...

Comment: just to add on to previous comment, try exchanging the id with `1020`, which is GTA V, having 1000+ reviews. you'll receive the full load of 100 ratings, as expected. also, if you play around with `limit`, lowering it below 25 for example, you'll see that the response is sensitive to that. it's really only this title having less than 100 reviews.. can you double check the results you saw in Postman?

Comment: (having checked the same request in Postman, I get the exact same response. 25 items for this game. in Postman as well, changing the id to 1020 for GTA V returns full 100 entries)